# R - Panel Data Long Form to 3-dimensional array of form person x time x feature

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, time-series

I'm trying to find an easy way in R to take a dataset with a person_id, date, and several variables fields (let's say 20, named x1, x2...x20) and convert it to a 3-dimensional array (m by n by p) where m is the number of people, n is the number of discrete time-periods, and p are the number of variables.

Current data appears as:

```
m1 n1 x1 x2 x3 ... x20    
m1 n2 x1 x2 x3 ... x20
m1 nN   . .  . ...  .
m2 n1 x1 x2 x3 ... x20
.  .  .  .  .  ...  .
.  .  .  .  .  ...  .
mM nN x1 x2 x3 x4 ... x2
```

In the end, I would like it to look like the following:

```
[, , 1]     
                    [, 1, ] [, 2, ] [, 3, ][, ..., ][, n, ]    
             [1, , ]    
             [2, , ]    
             [3 , ,]    
           [... , ,]    
             [m, , ]   
[, , 2]    
[, , 3]    
[, , ...]
[, , p]
```

For the sake of simplicity, we'll assume that the time-series is well-aligned (each m has exactly the same number of n).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use reshape2:

```
library(reshape2)
# You probably need to melt your data first
dataset.m <- melt(dataset, id.vars = c("m", "n"))

acast(dataset.m, m ~ n ~ variable)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I read through the melt and acast functions.  This will work perfectly.  I'd vote it up, but I don't have enough street cred yet.